# Functional way for custom iteration

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How can I use only `map`, `reduce` or `filter` or any functional way to create a custom iteration on an array?

Let's say I wanna map an array to another array which holds the sum of each three adjacent elements in the source array:

```
var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8] // to [6, 17, 8]
```

Or make a bucket of two elements:

```
var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] // to [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]
```

For the second one I have the following but that doesn't look very functional as I'm accessing array by index:

```
function* pairMap(data) {
    yield* data.map((item, index) => {
        if (index > 0) {
            return [data[index - 1], item];
        }
    });
}
```

I'm interested in the functional way of doing this.

Comment: There's a bunch of ways and those are two very separate problems. What have you tried?

Comment: Functional does not mean only using `map`, `reduce` and `filter`. Functional means it is declarative and where functions are first-class citizens afaik.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, that's my question. How do you do this in a `declarative` way?

Comment: When you figure out 2 you'll have a better understanding how you might get 1.

Comment: Are you against just using a "normal" `for` loop?  `var output = []; for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i+=2){ output.push([source[i], source[i+1]]); }` (or something like that)

Comment: Also, your `pairMap` function won't give the output you want.  The 1st iteration will be `undefined` and you will get pairs like `1, 2`, `2, 3`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Let's say I wanna map an array to another array which holds the sum of each three adjacent elements in the source array:
>
> ```
> var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8] // to [6, 17, 8]
> ```

Maps create 1:1 relationships, so this wouldn't be appropriate use of `map`. Instead, a `reduce` or ("fold") would be better here.

```
const comp = f=> g=> x=> f (g (x));
const len = xs=> xs.length;
const isEmpty = xs=> len(xs) === 0;
const concat = xs=> ys=> ys.concat(xs);

const chunk= n=> xs=>
  isEmpty (xs)
    ? []
    : concat (chunk (n) (xs.slice(n))) ([xs.slice(0,n)]);

const reduce = f=> y=> xs=> xs.reduce((y,x)=> f(y)(x), y);
const map = f=> xs=> xs.map(x=> f(x));
const add = x=> y=> y + x;
const sum = reduce (add) (0);

var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8];
comp (map (sum)) (chunk (3)) (source);
//=> [ 6, 17, 8 ]
```

So as you can see, we first transform the `source` into chunks of 3, then we `map` the `sum` function over each chunk.

When you hear people talking about "declarative" code, the last line is quite clear and worries little about implementation. We're not telling the computer *how* to do its job. There's no `for`/`while` loops, no extraneous vars or iterators, no logic, etc.

***"idgaf how, just break `source` up into groups of 3, and then sum each part"***

```
// very declaration, wow
comp (map (sum)) (chunk (3)) (source);
```

---

> Or make a bucket of two elements:
>
> ```
> var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] // to [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]
> ```

Using the same code above

```
var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
chunk (2) (source);
// => [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7 ] ]
```

---

> For the second one I have the following but that doesn't look very functional as I'm accessing array by index:
>
> ```
> function* pairMap(data) {
>       yield* data.map((item, index) => {
>          if (index > 0) {
>               return [data[index - 1], item];
>           }
>       });
>   }
> ```

Using the code above, you can implement `pairMap` easily

```
const pairMap = f=> comp (map (f)) (chunk (2));

var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
pairMap (pair => console.log(pair)) (source);
// [ 1, 2 ]
// [ 3, 4 ]
// [ 5, 6 ]
// [ 7 ]
```

---

**Learn all the things**

The question is "functional way for custom iteration". You'll notice my code sorta cheats by using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.map`. Learning how to build these on your own was a good learning tool for me to understand that building functional loops/iterators/control is fun and simple

```
const isEmpty = xs=> xs.length === 0
const head = xs=> xs[0];
const tail = xs=> xs.slice(1);

const reduce = f=> y=> xs=>
  isEmpty (xs)
    ? y
    : reduce (f) (f (y) (head (xs))) (tail (xs));

const add = x=> y=> y + x;
reduce (add) (0) ([1,2,3]);
//=> 6
```

It works!.

OK, let's see how we'd do map

```
const concat = xs=> ys=> ys.concat(xs);
const append = x=> concat ([x]);

const map = f=>
  reduce (ys=> x=> append (f (x)) (ys)) ([]);

const sq = x => x * x;
map (sq) ([1,2,3])
//=> [ 1, 4, 9 ]
```

**Quiz 1:** Can you write `filter`, `some`, and `every` using `reduce` ?

**Troll warning:** There's many different ways to implement these functions. If you start writing recursive functions, the first thing you'll want to learn about is what a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) is. ES6 is getting tail call optimization but it won't be widespread for a while. For a while, Babel could transpile it using a while loop, but it's temporarily disabled in version 6 and will be coming back once they fix it.

**Quiz 2:** How can you rewrite my `reduce` with a proper tail call?

Answer (score 2):

For first part of question you can use `reduce` and `slice` to group every 3 elements from array and then you can use `map` and `reduce` to get sum of each group.

```js
var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8];

var result = source.reduce((r, elem, i) => {
  if(i % 3 == 0) r.push(source.slice(i, i+3));
  return r;
}, []);

result = result.map(e => {return e.reduce((a, el) => { return a + el })});
console.log(result)
```

And for second part of question,  again you can use `reduce` with `slice` to group every 2 elements.

```js
var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

source = source.reduce((r, e, i) => {
  if(i % 2 == 0) r.push(source.slice(i, i+2));
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

First task with one `reduce`

```js
var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var r1 = source.reduce((p, c, i, a) => {
    if (i % 2) p[p.length - 1].push(c);
    else p.push([a[i]]);
    return p;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(r1, 0, 2));
```

Second task with `reduce` and `map`

```js
var source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var r2 = source.reduce((p, c, i, a) => {
    if (p[p.length - 1].length < 3) p[p.length - 1].push(c);
    else p.push([a[i]]);
    return p;
}, [[]]).map(e => e.reduce((a, b) => a + b));

console.log(JSON.stringify(r2, 0, 2));
```