# Javascript - can Array.prototype.find take a parameter to search for

Tags: javascript

I am looking at the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) but can not find what I am looking for.

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
 var valueToSearchFor = "something"

 function SearchArray(currentIndex, valueToSearchFor){
    return currentIndex.PropertyName === valueToSearchFor;
 }

 var attribute = myArray.find(SearchArray(valueToSearchFor));
```

rather than:

```
 var valueToSearchFor = "something"

 function SearchArray(currentIndex){
    return currentIndex.PropertyName === valueToSearchFor;
 }

 var attribute = myArray.find(SearchArray);
```

In my case the valueToSearchFor is not thread safe. Am I missing something?

Comment: *"In my case the valueToSearchFor is not thread safe"* Uh, what? How is that possible?

Comment: Could you maybe include a more specific reason as to what you mean by "_`valueToSearchFor` is not thread safe_"? JavaScript is single threaded

Comment: A similar question was just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947031/passing-additional-parameters-in-higher-order-functions . Maybe you can find your answer there.

Comment: If you change `SearchArray` to `function SearchArray(valueToSearchFor){ return function(currentIndex) { return currentIndex.PropertyName === valueToSearchFor; }; }` then your first example would work. But I still question whether you actually need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> in my case the valueToSearchFor is not thread safe

But regardless, you can still achieve this kind of functionality with currying:

```
var valueToSearchFor = "something";

function createSearchArray (valueToSearchFor) {
  return function (currentIndex) {
    return currentIndex.PropertyName === valueToSearchFor;
  }
}

var attribute = myArray.find(createSearchArray(valueToSearchFor));
```

The idea here is to create the function you're looking for using your `valueToSearchFor` variable. We then return this function to `.find()`.

Comment: In my case I am using web sockets which are not guaranteed to return values in order and all open connections have the same callback

Comment: @user1234 Ah okay. The sample code I provided is akin to a function builder, such that you give `createSearchArray` an argument for some `valueToSearchFor` and it will return a "search array" type function you can use with `.find()` — does that help with your issue?

Comment: Three cheers for [partial applications](http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/)!

Comment: @Sukima Functional programming always comes to the rescue ;)