# RoundRobin functional approach - why does my function have side effects?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

### Objective

I am trying to create a Round Robin algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling ) in a pure functional way.

This function, is supposed to received an array like the following:

```
[
    [ 1, 2 ],
    [ 3, 4 ]
]
```

And produce the following output:

`[ 1, 3, 2, 4 ]`

### Code

To achieve this, I decided to implement round robin recursively like the following:

```
const roundRobin = (arr, results) => {
    if (arr.length === 0) return results;

    const newResults = arr.reduce((acc, current) => {

        if (current.length > 0) {
            acc.results.push(current.shift());
            acc.arr.push(current);
        }
        return acc;

    }, { arr: [], results });

    return roundRobin(newResults.arr, newResults.results);
};
```

Here, I feel up an array of results, and I finish when I have nothing left to add to it. One would use this code like the following:

```
const array =     [
        [ 1, 2 ],
        [ 3, 4 ]
    ];

const result = roundRobin( array, [] );
```

### Problem

In my code I am using `reduce` in my `arr` parameter to ensure I don't modify the original. However, if I print array before using roundRobin and after, the variable is changed ! I mutate it somehow!

### Questions:

1. If I am using reduce, which is pure, how am I mutating my parameters?
2. Is there another pure/functional way of implementing roundRobin?

Comment: `shift()` does mutate the inner arrays

Comment: I don't get your input format. Can you explain what the array of arrays means?

Comment: Is the tail recursion (with an output parameter `result` that gets mutated) on purpose?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. If I am using reduce, which is pure, how am I mutating my parameters?

*Function parameters* can't really be mutated; a strange thought – but I'm sure you meant the *arguments* supplied to your function are being mutated. And yeah, that's with `.shift` as others pointed out

And for what it's worth, `.reduce` isn't pure unless the user-supplied lambda is pure

> 2. Is there another pure/functional way of implementing roundRobin?

Yep

```js
const isEmpty = xs =>
  xs.length === 0
  
const head = ( [ x , ...xs ] ) =>
  x
  
const tail = ( [ x , ...xs ] ) =>
  xs

const append = ( xs , x ) =>
  xs.concat ( [ x ] )
  
const roundRobin = ( [ x , ...xs ] , acc = [] ) =>
  x === undefined
    ? acc
    : isEmpty ( x )
      ? roundRobin ( xs , acc )
      : roundRobin ( append ( xs , tail ( x ) )
                   , append ( acc , head ( x ) )
                   )

const data =
  [ [ 1 , 4 , 7 , 9 ]
  , [ 2 , 5 ]
  , [ 3 , 6 , 8 , 10 , 11 , 12 ]
  ]
                   
console.log ( roundRobin ( data ) )
// => [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 ]

console.log ( roundRobin ( [ [ 1 , 2 , 3 ] ] ) )
// => [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]

console.log ( roundRobin ( [] ) )
// => []
```

Comment: This function is just... Beautiful!

Comment: i actually blushed *^_^*

Comment: I would changed this to the accepted answer if I could. I think you should know...

Comment: Ok, I finally managed it. You answer is now the officially accepted one!

Answer (score 3):

[Array#shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) is doing the mutating.

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
array.shift(); // -> 0
array; // -> [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

The easiest way around that is to clone the array. Usually that can be done with [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b) but since your arrays are nested (though simple) you can do this:

```
const roundRobin = (arr, results) => {
    arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
    if (arr.length === 0) return results;
    // ...
```

If you're concerned that the global `JSON` makes the function impure, you can abstract that out.

```
const deepClone = (obj) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
roundRobin(deepClone(array), []);
```

Comment: I really dislike the idea of converting things to strings and back. But I get the idea: do a clone.

Comment: I've not done much testing, but [it seems to be the most efficient way of doing things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript). I'm sure there are other techniques available but the idea is the important thing

Comment: Free variables are not impure – and that's not how you abstract a free variable; you make it a parameter of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to make immutable object in JS is to use `Object.freeze`.

I created your input array as:

```
const array1 = Object.freeze([
    Object.freeze([ 1, 2 ]),
    Object.freeze([ 3, 4 ])
])
```

Then, when I tried to call your function I got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add/remove sealed array elements
at Array.shift (<anonymous>)
at arr.reduce (<anonymous>:7:38)
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at roundRobin (<anonymous>:4:28)
at <anonymous>:6:17
```

You're using `shift`, which is mutating orignal array.

Replace it with `Array.slice(0,1)[0]` and it will start working.

Comment: If I do `current.slice(0, 1)[0]` the algorithm with simply stop working :S