# How to sort by Year and Month in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, indexof

I have an array organized as such.

```
const array = [
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Dec'
  },
  {
    Year: 2017,
    Month: 'Apr'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Mar'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Oct'
  },
  {
    Year: 2017,
    Month: 'Jan'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Apr'
  }
]
```

I have successfully organized the data by Year or by Month but every time I try to organize it by both of them at once, then whichever one organized the data last will supersede everything before it. I understand why it is doing this but can't seem to find a way around it.

```
const sortedByYear = array.sort((a, b) => a.Year - b.Year);
```

Sorts by year quite simply.

```
const sorted = sortedByYear.sort((a, b) => Months.indexOf(a.Month) - Months.indexOf(b.Month));
```

Sorts by Month.

I tried to add some sort of checker in the Month checker, if the years matched then resort but that doesn't solve the problem for how it will sort.

Comment: Sort by year, if they are the same - sort by month.

Comment: This is a fun use case for [contravariant functors](https://medium.com/@drboolean/monoidal-contravariant-functors-are-actually-useful-1032211045c4) – I share an answer demonstrating a multi-sort like the one you're trying to achieve here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47640811/633183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to put *both* tests in your `sort` function:

```js
const input = [
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Dec'
  },
  {
    Year: 2017,
    Month: 'Apr'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Mar'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Oct'
  },
  {
    Year: 2017,
    Month: 'Jan'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Apr'
  }
];
const Months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
input.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.Year !== b.Year) return a.Year - b.Year;
  return Months.indexOf(a.Month) - Months.indexOf(b.Month)
});
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash sortBy and pass the fields you want to *sort by* as an array.

`const sorted = _.sortBy(array, ['Year', 'Month']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of `year` and `month` to form a comparison criteria. [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Browser_compatibility) will not work on IE so you may need a polyfill for this.

```js
const input = [
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Dec'
  },
  {
    Year: 2017,
    Month: 'Apr'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Mar'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Oct'
  },
  {
    Year: 2017,
    Month: 'Jan'
  },
  {
    Year: 2018,
    Month: 'Apr'
  }
];
const Months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
input.sort((a, b) =>`${a.Year}${Months.indexOf(a.Month).toString().padStart(2,0)}` - `${b.Year}${Months.indexOf(b.Month).toString().padStart(2,0)}`
);
console.log(input);
```