# Chaining variable number of filter functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

let's say i wanted refactor this approach, rather than using a for loop, is there any other way
to  do this dynamically

```
  //to apply filter functions in one loop
  const booleanFilterFunctions = [
    (launchData) =>
      launchData.launch_year === filterState.year ||
      filterState.year === "0000",
    (launchData) => launchData.launch_success === filterState.launch,
    (launchData) => launchData.land_success === filterState.landing,
  ];
return (
 <div className={styles.grid}>
          {data
            .filter((launchData) => {
              let result = true;
              for (let i of booleanFilterFunctions)
                result = result && i(launchData);
              return result;
            })
            .map((launchData) => (
              <a key={launchData.flight_id} className={styles.card}>
                <img alt={launchData.links.mission_patch_small} loading="lazy" src={launchData.links.mission_patch_small}></img>

                <h3>
                  {launchData.mission_name} #{launchData.flight_number}
                </h3>
              </a>
            ))}
        </div>);
```

Comment: I think you want Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: hmm maybe but kind of a blurred line between review and asking for a better approach,
this certainly isn't for work :p

Comment: You might want to check out composing predicates using `And = (f, g) => x => f(x) && g(x)` and `Or = (f, g) => x => f(x) || g(x)` like I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53732612/3297291)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [array `every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for this:

```
data.filter(launchData =>
  booleanFilterFunctions.every(i => i(launchData))
)
```

Comment: i'm looking for a composition kind of way, every would take only 1 function, maybe i shoul have been more clear, what i want to do is 
getList of available functions let's say from a user,
apply them all in one go

Comment: @IshankSharma No, the `every` in my answer is called on that list of available functions (`booleanFilterFunctions`) and runs them all (`i(launchData)`). It does exactly the same thing as the loop in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying 3 filter functions one after the another, have you considered chaining the internal boolean logic? From the logic it looks like you want to show the content only when the 3 conditions are fulfilled. You can do something like this..

```
const filterData = (launchData) =>
  (launchData.launch_year === filterState.year ||
    filterState.year === "0000") &&
  launchData.launch_success === filterState.launch &&
  launchData.land_success === filterState.landing;


return (
 <div className={styles.grid}>
          {data
            .filter(filterData)
            .map((launchData) => (
              <a key={launchData.flight_id} className={styles.card}>
                <img alt={launchData.links.mission_patch_small} loading="lazy" src={launchData.links.mission_patch_small}></img>

                <h3>
                  {launchData.mission_name} #{launchData.flight_number}
                </h3>
              </a>
            ))}
        </div>);
```

You should be able to go even further on optimization and can avoid the extra iteration through data, by putting the condition directly on the content. Something like,

```
const shouldShowContent = (launchData) =>
  (launchData.launch_year === filterState.year ||
    filterState.year === "0000") &&
  launchData.launch_success === filterState.launch &&
  launchData.land_success === filterState.landing;


return (
 <div className={styles.grid}>
          {data
            .map((launchData) => shouldShowContent(launchData) && (
              <a key={launchData.flight_id} className={styles.card}>
                <img alt={launchData.links.mission_patch_small} loading="lazy" src={launchData.links.mission_patch_small}></img>

                <h3>
                  {launchData.mission_name} #{launchData.flight_number}
                </h3>
              </a>
            ))}
        </div>);
```

Comment: yes i have but that would default the purpose of question, to allow more dynamic behaviour

Comment: No, you should not "*put the condition directly on the content*". That will render an array of `false` values.

Comment: @Bergi right. But react doesn't render "false" value. That means it'll only render non-falsy elements. Let me know if I'm missing anything here.

Comment: Yes, react might filter them out for you, but it's still not a good practice to mix different types in the same array. The `.filter(shouldShowContent)` call is much cleaner (and there's hardly potential for micro-optimisation). At least use something like `shouldShowContent(launchData) ? <a>…</a> : null` if you think it's necessary.

Comment: Hmm.. right that makes sense to not have react render different types from the same array. Thanks!